# How to move scss to a new file in svelte 3?

Tags: sass, svelte, rollup, svelte-3, stylelint

I have a component App.svelte which has some scss code. I want to move my scss code to a new file so that i can run stylelint on the same. I am using rollup.js

```
<script>
  export let brandName = 'Stackoverflow';
</script>
<svelte:options tag="component-name"></svelte:options>

<main>
    <h1>Wizard <span class="span">{brandName}</span></h1>
</main>


<style lang="scss">
  h1{
    color: red;
    span {
      color: green;
    }
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the [svelte-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-preprocess) package to handle `.scss` files. You will need to update your `rollup.config.js`:

```js
// ...

import sveltePreprocess from "svelte-preprocess";

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
      // ...
```

You can then import your styles files like:

```html
<script>
    import "./styles.scss";
    // ...
</script>
```

[image: Edit stoic-brook-8iv5l]